# How to use Power shell script to extract and save attachments from Outlook to a local folder?

Tags: outlook, powershell-3.0

I am trying to extract and save attachments from outlook to a local folder and I am using the following script to do my work.

```
    Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$emails = $NameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders | where folderpath -match reports

$saveFilePath = "C:\temp\1\"


foreach ($email in $emails.items)
{
    if ($email.attachments.count -ge 1)
    {
        foreach ($attachment in $email.attachments)
        {
        $filename = $attachment.filename
        $attachment.saveasfile((join-path $savefilepath $filename))
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this script, I didn't get any errors, but the script didn't work.

Any suggestions please!!!

Answer (score 0):

$emails = $NameSpace.Folders.Item(1).Folders | where folderpath -match reports

Changed to:

where folderpath -match "reports"

Have you checked the folderpath to "reports"? I tested your code and update reports to My 
 folder "Inbox" (In double quotation marks) and it works.

I think the problem is reports condition.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hello Simon, thanks for helping me out. I tried it in your way, but it didn't worked for me. Any other suggestions or any other ways to perform this action???

Comment: And I suggest you debug step by step to see the value of this variable e.g. $emails. Please see my pic above.

Comment: Ok Simon, I'll try it and get back to you with my results. Thank you.

Comment: OK, you can also debug in the Windows PowerShell ISE. @PavanVadlapudi

Answer (score 0):

```
 It's likely that the path to the folder is incorrect. Here is updated code 
 with the full path hard coded for clarity


  Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
  $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
  $namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

  Function GetFilesFromEmail{
    $emails = 
  namespace.Folders.Item(2).Folders.Item('Inbox').Folders.Item('Dec 
Reports')
   
   $saveFilePath = "C:\temp\1\"
   
   foreach ($email in $emails.items)
       {
           if ($email.attachments.count -ge 1)
           {
               foreach ($attachment in $email.attachments)
                   {
                       $filename = $attachment.filename
                       $attachment.saveasfile((join-path $savefilepath 
  $filename))
                   }
           }
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).